# Integration of ln term

Tags: integration

$$ \int_{1/8}^{1/2}\left\lfloor\ln\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor\right\rfloor\,dx=\frac{a}{b}$$

where $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.

What is the value of $b-4a$?

I've thought of this a lot but could not get any start.

Can anybody provide me a hint?

Comment: @Kaynex there is greates integer function also

Comment: Can you draw the graph of your function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We observe that the function $\lfloor \ln\lfloor1/x\rfloor\rfloor$ is equal to 1 for ${1\over8}<x<{1\over3}$. The function is equal to zero for 
${1\over3}<x<{1\over2}$. Therefore we have
$$
\int_{1/8}^{1/2} \left\lfloor \ln\lfloor1/x\rfloor\right\rfloor dx = 
1\cdot\left({1\over3}-{1\over8}\right)= 5/24
$$
therefore 
$$
a=5, \qquad b=24,
$$
so $b-4a=4.$

**Note:** Here is a WolframAlpha command to plot the function:

```
plot floor(ln(floor(1/x))) from 1/8 to 1/2
```

Comment: How do you get that

Comment: By plotting a graph of the function and observing that it's either 0 or 1 on your integration interval. When $x\le1/3$ we have $1/x\ge3$... do I need to continue?

Comment: You accidentally wrote $\frac{1}{2}$ as the upper limit of the integral.

Comment: In the problem statement, 1/2 is in fact the upper limit. However, the function (integrand) is zero for ${1\over3}<x<{1\over2}$